# okhttp when api call is timed out data is still being sent to server

Tags: java, android, network-programming, okhttp

I am facing problem with okhttp in android.
when internet is not working smooth, i got time out from Okhttp, while server got what i sent. so I have not got any result back from server cuz of time out.
could anyone help me on this, I have tried increasing

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

but still get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout from callback onFailure of okhttp.

Comment: I guess you need to increase the timeout a little more.

Comment: 3 minutes is still short?